# Geometrical constructions using conics

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

Since Ancient Greece that there have been attempts to use conic sections to make geometrical constructions. Actually, it seems that the aim of Apollonius of Perga, while writing his treatise on conics, was to develop the properties of these curves necessary for their application to the solution of geometrical problems.

What is known about which problems can be solved using conics? Of course, this assumes that the expression “using conics” becames defined as precisely as “using compass and straightedge”. Has that study ever been made? I would like to have references about this. In fact, I am not so much interested in what *can* be done using conics. What I would like to know is what *can't* be done, in a way similar to the proof by [Pierre Wantzel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Wantzel) of the fact that the problems of doubling the cube and of trisecting an angle cannot be solved using compass and straightedge only.

Comment: Gauss used computations over cyclotomic fields to prove the sufficiency of condition "$n$ a product of powers of $2$ and Fermat primes" for [constructibility of a regular $n$-polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon), which Wantzel polished by supplying the necessity half of the proof.  So in a general sense problems can be solved when the answers lie in a tower of quadratic field extensions of the rationals.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, that's what can be done using compass and straghtedge only. But, for instance, you can also construct a regular $7$-gon and a regular $9$-gon using conics. What I would like to know is: which constructions can be made and, above all, wich constructions cannot be made using conics.

Comment: Okay, I was confused by your sentence, "Of course, this assumes that the expression 'using conics' bec[o]mes defined as precisely as 'using compass and straightedge", and I misunderstood that you for some reason were defining it to mean *precisely that*.  Sorry!

Comment: @hardmath No problem. I hope that you find my question interesting.

Comment: @MikhailKatz That question wasn't closed (but if it had been, my answer would be affirmative).

Comment: Do you have a source for constructing 7-gons and 9-gons using conics? Isn't it true that  only constructible numbers could be constructed using conics?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Construction of a regular $7$-gon and of a regular $9$-gon was achieved by islamic mathematitions in the late 10th century; see V. J. Katz, *A History of Mathematics: An introduction* (3rd edition), §9.5.2. The concept of constructible numbers has to do with constructions using compassa and straightedge only. Using conincs, we can in fact construct non-constrictible numbers (such as $\cos(20^\circ)$).

Comment: Is $\cos \pi/9$ algebraic?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Yes; it is a root of the polynomial $8x^3-6x+1$

Comment: Is it correct that any number constructed with conics would necessarily be algebraic? Why isn't this an answer to your question?

Comment: Even if it is true that number constructed with conics is necessarily be algebraic, how does that answer my question. How does that help me to determine whether or not I can construct, say, a regular $13$-gon?

Answer (score 2):

You might find Gibbins And Smolinsky's [Geometric Constructions With Ellipses](https://www.math.lsu.edu/%7Esmolinsk/GeometricConstructions_5_2.pdf) helpful.

In the final section it states that a regular polygon with $n$ sides is constructible with conics if and only if $\phi(n) = 2^s3^t$. (Here $\phi$ is the totient function, and the statement nicely parallels the requirement $\phi(n) = 2^s$ for ruler and compass constructions.

The proof is given in Videla's *On Points Constructible from Conics* (full reference in the G+S paper).

So, to your question in the comments, a 13-gon is constructible with conics because $\phi(13)=12$.

Comment: Thank you! I will read this.